# Using interface to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, interface, asp.net-4.0

```
interface IDbInteraction
{
    int GetValueAsInt(string sql);
}

class SQLDbInteraction : IDbInteraction
{
    private string _connStr;

    public SQLDbInteraction (string connStr)
    {
         _connStr = connStr;
    }

    public int GetValueAsInt(string sql)
    {
        int value;

            using(SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(_connStr))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                conn.Open();
                value = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

            }


        return value;
    }
}
```

This is a simple example on how to program an `interface` when access to a SQL Server database is needed.

It was offered to me as advice to replace an old code that I've presented in a question.

**So ...**, as I am fresh developer and new to the `interface` concept / approach / methodology, and as I don't really ***connect*** to the term `Repository` I've renamed that...

Could you please give a little broad example on how would you use these two : `class`  & `interface` above ?

And also if you could please offer alternative to `IRepository` (original name)

What would **you** replace it with (if you don't mind)?

As the point of this post, is about moving from the unsafe and kinda `obsolete` technique I was using, and now while trying to move on  to "*next generation*" coding methodology,

I could use your help on this sample code to learn usage.

### update

what i did now was researching the web.. and still, i have this issue in question :

is the way to call/invoke  `GetValueAsInt("select aColumn ...")`

now...when having an `interface` added  to the "equation" ,

**did it change anything as far as the invocation act cares ?**

do you still just call `GetValueAsInt()` as u did till now?

is it true that in this manner, nothing realy changed.. as for the actual usage

do you now call

```
IDbInteraction.GetValueAsInt("select aColumn from...")
```

or

```
SQLDbInteraction.GetValueAsInt("select aColumn from...")
```

or calling both ways is now availble ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface based programming is basically used to define a contract that a class must adhere to when being used.. Since you are new to this sort of terminology I would read up on Object Oriented Programming and Design Patterns where you will find out about implementations of the repository pattern.. IRepository is just an interface name you can name an interface whatever you like. Repository is a design pattern which is quite commonly used in business logic to data access layers. I am not sure that I would define this code as unsafe and obselete but you may decide to implment this logic using a design pattern and using object oriented techniques.

Comment: i did not mean to say that code above is obsolete it is the other way around, the code **I was** using is the one that's obsolete, then i've been offered by somone to use the code above as an alternative to my code , as my code was prone to injections

Comment: @T.U.B ... I've Updated my question, can you try and answer ?

Answer (score 1):

ok as i was expecting an answer... while still searching i came to conclusion

this is what i am going to implement

(say subject of application is colors)

```
IDbInteraction colorsData = new SQLDbInteraction("server=(local);Initial Catalog=...");
int colorId= colorsData.GetValueAsInt("SELECT colorId FROM colors WHERE name='jade'"));
```

as i will continue this search for the correct answer .if you see something wrong in my implementation please post your answer , if it is correct could somone please just upvote or something ?

Comment: If you get the correct data from your query then I can't really see very much wrong with what you're doing. No point in overcomplicating what seems to be a very simple query. I may be tempted to put the DB string in a config file so it can be changed easily and the query in a const string but other than that it looks ok.

Comment: @TheUnculledBadger cheers mate I am now with already 2 classes ( i have many of them as helpers) moved to use interfaces, i guess i'll see the point later on while using it (as to why exactly do they exist... besides microsoft leting you feel in another way you can not leave "school" and relationsheep with new products)

Comment: You will see the point when you start unit testing the functionality. Using interfaces will allow you to much more easily unit test any code.